# Issue "Exploded location overlaps an existing deployment" (MyEclipse 10.0 Blue & Websphere7 )

Tags: websphere-7, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 10.0 Blue & Websphere7. I do deployment in eclipse from 'Servers' tab (window > show view > Servers)

I am getting below issue even though Websphere is not having particual ear.

```
"Exploded location overlaps an existing deployment"
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got the work around for this problem. Perform below steps in MyEclipse Blue 10.0 IDE:

1. Remove WebSphere profile (server instance) from Window > Preferences > WebSphere 7.0
2. Again re-load profile by selecting WebSphere home directory (Windows > Preferences > WebSphere 7.0)
3. Clean the project
4. To deploy your project ear/war in WebSphere go to Window > show view > Servers
5. Right click on WebSphere 7 in Servers tab
6. Do deployment from 'Add Deployment...'
7. Select your project and finish it

Answer (score 0):

Narendra, we fixed several bugs in this area, especially the "overlapping" deployment problem that you are running into in subsequent MyEclipse releases of the 10.x series.

I would recommend updating to MyEclipse 10.7.1. You can download an installer from our website http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-4.html or apply the update within your 10.0 installation from Software tab in the MyEclipse configuration center (Help > MyEclipse Configuration Center).

Hope this helps,
Brian.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the reply. Due to some project restriction, I cannot upgrade to MyEclipse 10.7.1 for now. Whenever we will switch to MyEclipse 10.7.1, I will definitely keep my eyes on this issue. For now, this issue is resolved. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit the problem in MyEcliplseBlue 9, and I resolved it by ensuring the project had indeed gone from the location AppSrv01/installedApps/(node name)/,   removing the profile,
then stopping the WAS server, stopping and starting the IDE, recreating the profile and then I was able to redeploy the app.

I think something cached got out of sync.

Answer (score -1):

We can create one more profile in websphere. It will update the deploymnet info where we are facing exploded issue.
It worked some time for me.

Answer (score -1):

Problem: Due to removal of ear/war directly from Deploy directory (%JBOSS_HOME%\server\default\deploy); instead of removal of ear/war from IDE.

Therefore please select:

1. Servers->Right click on (Installed Server) -> Add Deployment ->
2. Earlier you chose "Exploded Deployment", now choose "Packeged Archive" Deployment.
3. Once deployment done, Right click on (Deployed ear/war) and choose "Remove Deployment"

Now you can deploy your ear by using "Exploded Archive" deployment successfully.*